# Chrome Apps on Mobile with Apache Cordova. Is Apache Cordova released or i sit in developer phase?

Tags: cordova-chrome-app, apache-cordova

We are planning to build chrome apps for mobile devices for an enterprise product. I want to know whether Apache Cordova has released version. 
 
When I go to this https://developer.chrome.com/apps/chrome_apps_on_mobile, it say it is in developer preview. what does that mean

 
Can we use it to release the apps for enterprise product.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't build a regular cordova application ?

Comment: We are trying to build chrome apps for desktop and want to do the same for mobile with technologies HTML5, CSS and Javascript